# () Parentheses after functor but not function pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, functor, template-specialization, parentheses

Below is a simple example, with stuff that bugs me. Also a link to an online c++ compiler with given example is here https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/oxQd8FU2NV

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void PrintF (const T& printInt) { cout << printInt << " "; }

template <class T>
class PrintClass {
public:
void operator()(T elem) const {
    cout << elem << " ";
}
};

int main () {
vector<int> vect;
for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) {
    vect.push_back(i);
}


for_each (vect.begin(), vect.end(), PrintClass<int>()); cout << endl;

for_each (vect.begin(), vect.end(), PrintF<int>);      cout << endl;

//  for_each (vect.begin(), vect.end(), PrintF<int>() );  
//  won't compile because of ()  in PrintF<int>()

return 0;
}
```

Why can't we write **`PrintClass<int>()`** without (), like this **`PrintClass<int>`** (first for_each line) ?

And when using function (not function object) we must not use () (second for_each line),so we write like this `PrintF<int>` ?

How should I interpret/parse the 3rd argument in these two for_each functions ?

Comment: I'm curious what people are finding unclear about this. There's a complete code sample to play with and a contrast of the two forms of argument, followed by a direct question with "desired" code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PrintF<int>` is a function. We're passing the function to `for_each`. Putting parentheses would be incorrect, as we'd be attempting to (unsuccessfully) call the function.

`PrintClass<int>` is a class. We can't pass classes around, as they're not values. We can, however, pass instances of that class around, so we make an instance of the class and pass it. The following two calls would have the same result

```
for_each (vect.begin(), vect.end(), PrintClass<int>());
```

```
PrintClass<int> myFunction = PrintClass<int>();
for_each (vect.begin(), vect.end(), myFunction);
```

Comment: your example PrintClass<int> myFunction = PrintClass<int>(); cleared it in my mind.Tanks. I'm just not used to create object(s) on stack like that, but only like  PrintClass<int> myFunction. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`std::for_each` requires an object that can be used like a function.  When you use

```
for_each (vect.begin(), vect.end(), PrintF<int>);
```

`PrintF<int>` decays to a pointer to the `PrintF<int>` function and then `for_each` can use that pointer to call the `PrintF<int>` function.

In

```
for_each (vect.begin(), vect.end(), PrintClass<int>());
```

`PrintClass<int>` is the name of a class, it isn't an object.  You need the `()` at the end to tell the compiler to make a temporary object of the type `PrintClass<int>` and then `for_each` can use that object to call its `operator ()`.

Comment: std::for_each requires function pointer or a move constructible function object.  [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/?kw=for_each]

Comment: @Redacted, no, it does not require move constructible object.

Comment: @Redacted requiring that the function object is *MoveConstructible* encompasses copy construction.  The requirement is the whatever is passed must be callable (`name_of_thing(var1, var2)` must be valid), and it can be copied or moved.

Comment: Using `{}` in `PrintClass<int>{}` would also help disambiguate _function calling_ from _object construction_.